# AlertDialog not loading

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have a `ListView` and i have put an `onClickListener` to it. When i click it, it is supposed to run an `AlertDialog` but it does not seem to work. The `AlertDialog` is supposed to display a few strings which are in the `ListView`. here is the code I am using.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                PopUpAlert(id);

            }
        });


 private void PopUpAlert(final long id) {

            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllReviewRows(id);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                //Preparing variables to use in message from Establishment record in Database

                final String SName = cursor.getString(dbHelper.COL_REV_STATION_NAME);
                String Date = cursor.getString(SQL.COL_DATE);
                String SFacility = cursor.getString(SQL.COL_REV_FACILITY);
                String Rating = cursor.getString(SQL.COL_RATING);
                String Comment = cursor.getString(SQL.COL_COMMENTS);

                // building a drill down information message and displaying it in an Alert Dialog
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Facilities Review App")
                        .setMessage("You Selected:\n"
                                + "Station Name: " + SName + "\n" + "Date: " + Date
                                + "\n" + "Facility: " + SFacility + "\n" + "Rating: " + Rating
                                + "\n" + "Comment: " + Comment)
                        .setPositiveButton("Add Image", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // calling method to add a review for that particular establishment
                                addImage(SName);

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // calling method to delete that particular establishment


                            }


                        });

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't call `show()` on your `AlertDialog`:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
 .setTitle("Facilities Review App")
 .setMessage("...")
 .setPositiveButton(..)
 .setNegativeButton(..)
 .show();
```

Here you can find the documentation for [AlertDialog.Builder.show()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#show())